# What is the correct way to give the Jenkins agent image access to docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

The Jenkins controller and Jenkins agent are supposedly able to be run in Docker;

Under Jenkins' official installation instructions, **Docker** is the first option listed:

- [User Handbook -> Installing Jenkins -> Docker](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/)

They also appear to have an [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/ssh-agent) for a Jenkins agent that can used by a dockerized Jenkins controller.

The agent image doesn't work out of the box. I had to extend the image to install `git`. I tried passing the docker binary and socket via `volumes` in my `docker-compose.yml` file. This worked for the controller with the builtin node, but does not appear to work here.

```
  jenkins-agent:
    build: ./jenkins-agent
    container_name: jenkins-agent
    privileged: true
    user: root
    container_name: agent
    expose:
      - 22
    environment:
      - JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=<omitted>
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

I get the following error:

```
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I think this is because the `jenkins` user doesn't have permission to do this. I tried adding a docker group in the container and `usermod -aG docker jenkins`. I tried adding a jenkins user to the host and `usermod -aG docker jenkins`. I didn't expect either to work, and neither did.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add a group named `docker` in the container, you should add a group with the same GID of the `docker` group in the host machine, no matter if it is called docker or somehow else: the only thing that matters is its GID. For example, it is possible that you image will already have a group named `ping` that has that GID. The only thing to do is add the `jenkins` user to that group.

The best thing is to create a script in the entrypoint of the image, that detect the GID of the mounted `/var/run/docker.sock` at runtime and to the trick for you. Assuming your image is based on an Alpine version of `jenkins/ssh-agent`, a possible entrypoint could be this `entrypoint.sh` file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# 
# These tricks allow to add jenkins user to the group of /var/run/docker.sock
# that has been bind mounted from the host. Usually, it has permissions 660,
# but the GID of the group refers to the host system, so we have to create
# a group with the same GID and assign it to the jenkins user.

# Get GID of /var/run/docker.sock
GID=$(stat -c %g /var/run/docker.sock)

# Try to create a new system group named docker with that PID
# May fail if the current system already has a group with the same GID.
addgroup -S -g $GID docker

# Get the name of the group with the GID.
# Could be different from "docker" if a group with that GID already existed.
GNAME=$(getent group $GID | cut -d: -f1)

# Add user jenkins to the group
addgroup jenkins $GNAME

# Eventually, launch the original jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine-jdk11 entrypoint
setup-sshd
```

And a possible Jenkinsfile could be

```dockerfile
FROM jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine-jdk11

# Add Docker CLI
RUN apk add --no-cache docker-cli

# Add custom entrypoint to handle jenkins user access to Docker socket
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint.sh"]
```